# How to get photo creation date in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, metadata, photo-gallery

I am trying to get picture taken date while choosing picture from Photo Library in iPhone. I am using below code to do the same.

```
NSDictionary* fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
NSDate *result = [fileAttribs fileCreationDate]; //or fileModificationDate
```

But it is showing current date and time.

Is there any way to get picture taken date while choosing picture from Photo library.

Comment: check this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688983/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-any-way-of-getting-the-date-of-the-chosen-picture

Answer (score 3):

You can do it checking the metadata of the picture with [ALAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Look for the key `ALAssetPropertyDate`

EDIT, complete code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:url
                   resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                       NSDate *myDate = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                       NSLog(@"Date: %@", myDate);
                   } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"Error");
                   }];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Please, check the docs, try it for yourself and if it doesn't work, come back with a specific question.

Comment: Okay I checked. My code is:

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:fileUrl];
    
    ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    
    //The key UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL allows you to get an ALAsset, which then allows you to get metadata (such as the date the media was created)
    [lib assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        NSLog(@"created: %@", asset);
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];

Output is: created: (null)

Comment: Get the url like this: NSURL* url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

Comment: I cant do that because I am using phonegap.. I get url from phonegap plugin like below:

file://localhost/Users/shivam/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/3007041C-CEA0-4A8C-884D-91F8268542D4/tmp/cdv_photo_004.png

Comment: Then I can't help you. There must be something wrong with that url.

Answer (score 0):

ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated, so with PHAsset:

```
#import <Photos/PHAsset.h>
```

Then:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
        PHAsset *phAsset = [[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[imageURL] options:nil] lastObject];
        NSDate *date = [phAsset creationDate];
        UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

}
```